# In Java is it possible to assign a method reference to a variable whose class has a generic type?

Tags: java, generics

Let's say we've got the following classes:

```
interface Event {
}

@FunctionalInterface
interface EventListener<T extends Event> {
  void onEvent(T event);
}

class Service {

  class ServiceEvent implements Event {
  }

  public void onServiceEvent(ServiceEvent event) {
  }
}
```

Why does the following assignment compile without any problems:

```
Service service = new Service();
EventListener<ServiceEvent> listener = service::onServiceEvent;
```

but this one:

```
Service service = new Service();
EventListener<? extends Event> anotherListener = service::onServiceEvent;
```

fails with this compile error:

`Error: java: incompatible types: invalid method reference incompatible types: Event cannot be converted to Service.ServiceEvent`

Comment: What happens if you say `EventListener<? extends Event> anotherListener = null;` ?

Comment: @MikeNakis It's perfectly legal. It will be compiled without any problems.

Comment: I get where you are coming from, but think about it another way. The definition of `anotherListener` allows you to call `anotherListener.onEvent` with anything that extends `Event`. The compiler cannot ensure proper usage in that case, and generics are all about type safety at compile time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public void onServiceEvent(ServiceEvent event) {}
```

This accepts only `ServiceEvent` parameters. Just like:

```
EventListener<ServiceEvent> listener = service::onServiceEvent;
```

but:

```
EventListener<? extends Event> anotherListener
```

Can accept not only `ServiceEvent` but also all subtypes of the `Event` type. Hence, the type mismatch

Comment: And yet you can do `anotherListener = listener` without any problem.

Comment: @RealSkeptic yeah, I see - I switched the order of assignment

Comment: @RealSkeptic I've seen a similar question here recently with a good answer - I will try do find that

Comment: @RealSkeptic Should there not be a unchecked cast warning? Generic oddity?

Comment: @Maaaatt Nope. It's just like `List<? extends Number> x = new ArrayList<Integer>()`. It's perfectly compatible. You wouldn't be able to use it, though.